# How can i distinguish revenue from different folders in Adsense?

Tags: google-adsense

I am currently running three websites using adsense. Since i do this more to be useful than to earn something, i have a subdomain of a free hoster and my websites live in subfolders e.q. mydomain.hoster.com/website1, mydomain.hoster.com/website2, to which i link with .tk aliases.

Is there a way to distinguish adsense income from website1 to website 2?

I tried using custom channels, but somehow this part of adsense eludes me. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link your Google AdSense account to Google Analytics account: https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012183&topic=1038753&parent=1120718&rd=1

Then you will be able to slice and dice your AdSense revenue from inside Analytics dashboard, which has much more powerful reporting capabilities.